# How to pass values of variables in OCaml

Tags: if-statement, variables, ocaml

In imperative languages I can easily write something like this:

```
if(x > y) {
        int t = x;
        x = y;
        y = t;
    }
```

The values of the variables are getting passed to another. However if I try writing this in Ocaml, the compiler sees this as a comparison, so it turns out to be bool:

```
if x > y then 
          let t = x in
          let x = y in
          let y = b in
```

How can I pass the value of variables to another?

Comment: This is not generally possible in OCaml, and is one of the defining differences between functional and imperative languages. Although you can use ref cells to create mutable variables, that is not idiomatic and you would be better off taking a step back and look at the bigger problem to see if there's a way to do it without mutating variables.

Comment: I would consider this question an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Don't try to force imperative solutions in OCaml. Swim _with_ the current and look for a functional solution.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than variables, OCaml has named values. If you want to shuffle the names of some values, you can write:

```ml
let x, y =
 if x > y then y, x
 else x, y
in
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to mirror the imperative code exactly you would write:

```
# let x = ref 2;;
val x : int ref = {contents = 2}
# let y = ref 1;;
val y : int ref = {contents = 1}

# let swap_if x y = if !x > !y then let t = !x in x := !y; y := t;;
val swap_if : 'a ref -> 'a ref -> unit = <fun>

# swap_if x y;;
- : unit = ()

# !x, !y;;
- : int * int = (1, 2)
```

Writing it functional you would do

```
let (x, y) = if x > y then (y, x) else (x, y)
```

or

```
let (x, y) = (min x y, max x y)
```

But note that this will not change `x` and `y`. Rather it creates new variables `x` and `y` that shadow the previous bindings.

Comment: May be you intended ... `let swap (x, y) = if x > y then (y, x) else (x, y)`!!! But anyways, a plus from me for the pattern.

Comment: No, I mend that as direct assignment. You can make a `swap` function but it isn't swapping so it would be a misnomer. And you have to use it like this: `let (x, y) = swap (x, y) in ...`